# How to Install SSL certificate in Linux Servers

Tags: linux, wcf, ssl, mono, monodevelop

I am trying to access https wcf web service from my application using monodevelop in Linux. The web service call is throwing the following exception

> SendFailure (Error writing headers)  at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) [0x00043] in
>   /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:845
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel+c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0
>   (IAsyncResult r) [0x0001d] in
>   /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/HttpRequestChannel.cs:219.

when I try to load the web service url using https, the Firefox browser is giving a warning:

> "This connection is Untrusted"

The certificate(.cer) is generated using Visual Studio 2008 makecert utility.I tried to install certificate using the below commands

1. certmgr -add -c -m My MyCert.cer
2. certmgr -ssl https://myserver.com:1200/Monik/TestSvc

But it looks like the certificates are not configured properly. In some of the forums it saying that move the certificate to **/etc/httpd/conf**  . But there is no such folder in my system

Please let me know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Mono handles certificates via [mozroots](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mozroots) so best thing in your case would probably be to run this:

```
sudo mozroots --import --machine --sync
sudo certmgr -ssl -m https://myserver.com:1200/Monik/TestSvc
```

First command will synchronise public root certificates. Second will ask you if you want to trust your server certificate which will be displayed to you after entering command. Type "yes".

Comment: Karlas, Just I applied the command certmgr -delete to remove the certficate from the certificate stores CA, TRUST and the AddressBook.  After this my application was started working. I never added the certificates to any other store except 'My".